# swift fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value(lldb)-in my code?

Tags: swift

This is my code here found the `fatal error`.,and it shows the

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_i386_INVOP,subcode=0*0)

```
let email: NSString = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("fb_email")! as NSString
```

Comment: you can check if `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` is returning nil by assigning it to an optional. and then check that optional for value.

Comment: Great, but this is my answer. And doesn`t seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("fb_email")` is nil. When you try to unwrap it with `!`, a fatal error occurs.

Try this:

```
if let object = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("fb_email") {
    // do sth. with object
} else {
    // error
}
```

Comment: where should i find the fatal error and use the unwrap ! it?

Comment: hmm then maybe already `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` produces nil??

Comment: how should we assigned NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() is to !nil?